# Does this dual-WAN setup seem sensible? NBN + 5G failover

Tags: networking, home-networking, wan

I have an HFC internet connection, which takes the form of an ISP-managed Network Termination Device (you can't even log into it, you just have to stare sadly at the status lights) hooked up to a cheap TP-Link modem / router combo unit (as far as I can tell, this just does VLAN tagging).

The TP-Link doesn't have great WiFi, so I have it running with WLAN turned off and cabled in to a Google WiFi hub, which meshes out to nodes elsewhere in the house. Most of my devices are on WiFi. The Google Wifi also has one ethernet jack, so I've got it connected to a Netgear Switch that my PC, media / home automation server etc run off.

This internet connection is unreliable (not config specific, just Australia) so I experience a few <30s dropouts per day, and a multi-day dropout every second or third month. I've picked up a 5G Huawei modem, which has relatively expensive bandwidth but has (thus far) worked when the HFC drops out. At the moment, I just unplug the TP-link from the WAN port of the Google Hub, and plug the Huawei in. All my smart home devices (on the WLAN) and all the wired clients Just Work which is pretty neat.

I'm thinking of buying a Peplink Balance 2/20 (I don't need or want the WiFi, but they're cheap as chips second hand). As I understand it, I can feed both of my WANs into the Peplink, and (with some basic config) I can set it to do a hot failover to the 5G when the HFC breaks completely, or falls below some acceptable speed threshold. This way I get the cheap bandwidth of HFC most of the time, but a reliable connection by occasionally and automatically swapping over to 5G.

Am I understanding the hardware here correctly / will this work? I'm aware there are cheaper routers that will do what I want, but I figure it's only an extra $50 for the Peplink and I like the look of it.

If traffic is blended across both WANs when HFC slows down but hasn't broken entirely, what happens to my external IP? How can traffic reach the internet from two WANs at once?

My server runs ddclient for Dynamic DNS so I can access my home automation setup when I'm away from home. How will this handle sudden, occasionally short changes between WANs? Is there a trick with either my local setup or my DNS records that helps here?

Will I still be able to open the ports I need through this double (triple?) NAT setup?

Thanks in advance and sorry if these are dumb questions - happy to post somewhere else if there's a more appropriate forum.

Comment: For potential answerers NBN is Aussies "fibre rollout" which is often actually VDSL - at least in the 2 CBD offices I supported.

Comment: The nbn connection should not be that unreliable - gave you considered a different telco with different gear? What is the model if the Telco router? (we maybe able to ascertain the type of connection and give additional recommendations)